# Is the Bitcoin Core software managed by a central authority?

Tags: bitcoin-core, decentralization, transaction-propagation

Is the Bitcoin Core software managed by a central authority? It is in the context, that once a transaction is broadcast by a user, then is it centrally published at the application level (i.e Bitcoin Core) or it is propagated physically to every other user through the Bitcoin network?

Comment: I didn't know what "virtual blockchain network" is supposed to be, so I replaced it with "Bitcoin network" which I think is what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

It is propagated server-to-server and, with luck, eventually gets to a bunch of miners who will include it in a block. There is no central authority -- individual servers are free to propagate transactions using whatever rules they wish.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin is open-source and relies on decentralization to achieve trustless consensus for transactions.

**Ultimately, however, maintaining the Bitcoin Core code and deciding the direction of development has in practice been influenced primarily by a small (but growing) group of individuals.**  Scroll to the bottom of this page - https://bitcoin.org/en/development - for a list of contributors.  Blockstream is also an authority on how Bitcoin development progresses, and many from their team - https://blockstream.com/team/ - are among that list of contributors.  The current 'Core vs. Unlimited' debate illustrates how, if other Bitcoin participants believe Core development is not addressing concerns adequately and/or is under control of bad actors* they can present alternative code, which miners may freely choose instead.  With enough of the network's hashrate this would cause a 'fork'.

**Mining power can be centralized too, and is to some extent today**, which leaves the network vulnerable to bad actors in what is commonly called a 51% attack (for close calls of the past and a larger discussion: http://www.coindesk.com/51-attacks-real-threat-bitcoin/).

**These vulnerabilities are well-known and have been discussed for years without a perfect solution.  With appropriate checks, balances, and participation from the community we mitigate the risks of development or mining truly becoming managed by a central authority; but with economic incentives present for certain actions, Bitcoin may always fall somewhere between decentralized and centralized.  There *is* strong consensus in the community that this is still better than our traditional alternatives.**

*not to imply either as fact in that debate; just for a relevant framework

Comment: When you say "direction of development has in practice been influenced primarily by a small (but growing) group of individuals", do you mean small in comparison to the number of users?  Why is that a valid argument towards Bitcoin being more centralised?